# Pass object from one generic method where T : MyClass to another where T : DerivedClass

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a generic repository which contains this method:

```
public void Delete<T>(T item) where T : EntityBase
```

I'm trying to add soft-delete behaviour to some objects; ie. when deleted they are not removed from the database, but instead a `bool Deleted` is set to `false` and they stop showing up in queries unless a specific parameter is set to include them. In general, the application behaves as if they aren't there, with the exception of the admin views where these items can be restored by flipping that bool back again. My problem is that in passing the object to this method, it's being handled as `EntityBase`, which doesn't have this soft-delete behaviour because many classes don't need it. `SoftDeleteEntityBase` extends the `EntityBase` class to add the soft-delete behaviour, but I can't find a clean way to cast objects so that I can get at the bool. My first thought was this:

```
public void Delete<T>(T item) where T : EntityBase
{
    if (item is SoftDeleteEntityBase)
    {
        ((SoftDeleteEntityBase)item).Deleted = true;
        Update<T>(item);
    }
    else
    {
        db.Set<T>().Remove(item);
    }
}
```

but that gives me the error `"Cannot convert type T to SoftDeleteEntityBase"`.

How do I get at that bool?

Comment: (item as SoftDeleteEntityBase).Deleted = true;

Comment: @JohnLiu possible `NullReferenceException`

Comment: Thanks llya, Assume check at beginning of function. not this statement.

Comment: @JohnLiu Actually... yeah, swapping that line out works. I'm not quite sure how I remembered I could use `is` in the check, but forgot that I could use `as` in the conversion. If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: It is fine, thanks. I suggest you to think about the way how you handle soft delete. looks like you are hiding business logic into Infrastructure component.

Comment: Since posting I've actually reconsidered where I should put this. Several times. On the one hand, soft delete seems to be pretty separate from specific business logic; some stuff you just want to archive. On the other hand, deciding *what* gets soft-deleted is very much a business-logic issue. I think it might be more sensible to not call `Delete()` on things that have soft-delete behaviour; instead, set `Deleted = true` and call `Update()` in the logic, rather than hiding that operation in the repository. It just seems cleaner that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this short solution, but consider to change the design of your repositories

```
SoftDeleteEntityBase itemAsSoft = item as SoftDeleteEntityBase;
if (itemAsSoft != null)
{
    itemAsSoft.Deleted = true;
    Update(itemAsSoft);
}
```

I don't know your context, but what about this solution with wrap around generics

```
void Main()
{
    Delete(new Base()); // called with base
    Delete(new Derived()); //called with derived
}
public void Delete(Base item)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("called with base");
    //one logic
    GenericDelete(item);
}

public void Delete(Derived item)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("called with derived");
    //another logic
    GenericDelete(item);
}

public void GenericDelete<T>(T item)
{}

public class Base
{}

public class Derived : Base
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you'd leverage polymorphism.  The `EntityBase` class can have a `Delete` method; it and other implementations could choose to do a hard delete.  The `SoftDeleteEntityBase` class can override that method and instead choose to just set a `Deleted` field instead of hard deleting it.  Then this method here doesn't need to care what the derived type is; it can just call `Delete` and let the class choose for itself.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how that would work... this repository manipulates my database via Entity Framework, so I'd have to pass the whole data context into the object's `Delete` method, which seems messy to me.